# Raspberry Pi and Elk stack

Tags: elasticsearch, raspberry-pi, logstash, kibana

Would it be possible to setup a distributed ELK stack on multiple raspberry pi?

I know that it is possible to run the ELK stack on a raspberry pi but I'm interested if anyone as a guess on how it would perform and the general system architecture it would require?

Also I am aware that this is a strange idea but I'm interested in it as a proof of concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? [Definitely](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3s1ypn/i_set_up_an_elasticsearch_cluster_using_raspberry/) [Yes](https://www.google.ch/search?q=elasticsearch+raspberry).

Efficient? Probably not! Because depending on how far apart the Pis are, the network latency would kill the performance of your cluster.

You can definitely do it on a few Pis in your home network, you'll need to figure out the best parameters (see links above) but that will work. Now, I would never use that as a production cluster :-)